# Probability of choosing 4 sick people from 100 where there is a probability of 8.6% for each of them to have a disease.

Tags: probability, bayesian

I have the following task:
There is 4% of sick people in a population.
There is 5% chance for a positive test for a healthy person.
There is 2% chance for a negative test for a a sick person.
We tested 100 people and 4 had a positive test.
What is the probability of such an outcome?

So far I found that the probability for a test to be positive is 0.086, but I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: this belongs on the stats stackexchange: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: The probability being tested positiv is $P=0.05\cdot(1-0.04)+(1-0.02)\cdot0.04$. Now the number of people out of $100$ tested positive follows a binomial distribution with $n=100$ and that $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your overall positivity rate is correct: You then have a binomial probability situation where you want to know the probability of 4 successes in 100 trials.

Comment: Thank you, but how do you know it follows binomial probability?

Comment: Because the overall probability of a test being positive is a fixed value, and you want the probability of 4 out of 100 being positive.

Answer (score 0):

Take this answer with a grain of salt, and call me in the morning. The probability of getting a positive result is .0872, as they commented above. IF the probability follows the binomial PMF, then (nCk)(p^k)(q^n-k) gives .0356 or 3.5%. If there is a different distribution, then we may be off the mark.

Comment: Why could there be a different distribution?

Comment: That's a good question. PAW88789 may be correct, I just don't have any knowledge of the specifics in medical testing. Binomial PMF approximates Normal PMF, and that is very common. But, I can't say for sure, in this case.